# Prevent divs from filling empty space?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to display an address using a div layout so that the address will be displayed something like this:

Customer Name: John Doe

Address Line 1: Example Street 13

Address Line 2:

Postal Code: 90210

My current layout works fine as long as I have data in every field, but if for an example the value for Address Line 2 is nothing/empty then the layout breaks because the divs for Postal Code moves up on the same line as Address Line 2.

I've made a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwfzp/2/

What changes should I make to the CSS in order to make it work?

CODE:

```
<div class="display-label">
    Customer Name:
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    John Doe
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    Address line1:
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    Example street 13
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    Address line2:
</div>
<div class="display-field">
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    Postal code::
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    90210
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-label
{
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight:bold;   

}

.display-field
{
    margin-left: 160px;
    font-size:small;
}
```

Best regards
Christian

Comment: I would create an HTML helper that didn't output the `div` at all if the data was empty.

Comment: I guess `<br/>` tag can be used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float both `.display-label` and `.display-field` to the left, `float: left;` and add `clear: left;` to `.display-label`.  I removed the margin from `.display-field` and added some padding.

The `clear: left;` will prevent all the divs from lining up in a single line and push it down below the div preceding it.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwfzp/4/

**CSS**

```
.display-label
{
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight:bold;  
    clear: left; 

}

.display-field
{
    float: left;
    font-size:small;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
This is as far as I can see the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS:

```
.display-label
{
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight:bold;   
    clear:both;
}

.display-field
{
    margin-left: 160px;
    font-size:small;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
This however places the values to the far right, im looking for a solution where the values are placed close to the label.
(Sorry, but I forgot to specify it in my question)

Answer (score 0):

Specify an equal height for both elements on CSS style, e.g.

```
.display-label
{
float:left;
width: 150px;
text-align:right;
font-size:small;
font-weight:bold;
height: 20px;
}
.display-field
{
margin-left: 160px;
font-size:small;
height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply. It work!
I guess the big question is why does it work when a height of 20px is defined?

Comment: Coz of equal line-heights ! when there is no character within a Div and its just filled with space(!), height of Div differs from when its filled with visible chars. this way we force divs to have equal heights in both conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element :after to append a non-visible space.

[See your adjusted JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zwfzp/7/)

```
.display-field:after
{
    content: '&nbsp;';
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP or JavaScript to check for the empty fields that needed to be remove on output.